# Can't ssh into EC2 instance once VPN client connected

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, iptables, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server in a EC2 instance. I installed expressvpn client in this server (which I'm using regularly in my home servers without any issues).

Once the VPN connection starts on the  server I am no longer able to connect to the server from my laptop. I also have an Apache server running on the server that also unreachable at this point.

Is there anyway to fix this.
I understand that this could happen due to a weird way of configuration in AWS. In that case, is there a way to force all traffic to port 22 to a specific non-VPN interface like eth0?

Output of `ip rule` , `iptables -nvL` and `ip route`

**before connecting vpn**

```
Tue Apr 21 21:51:01 UTC 2020
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
---------
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 7536 packets, 1858K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7340 packets, 2732K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
---------
default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 172.31.35.37 metric 100
172.31.32.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.35.37
172.31.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.35.37 metric 100
```

**After connecting to vpn**

```
Tue Apr 21 21:53:01 UTC 2020
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
---------
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 8168 packets, 2072K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7954 packets, 2896K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
---------
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.150.0.21 dev tun0
default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 172.31.35.37 metric 100
10.0.0.0/8 via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0
10.150.0.1 via 10.150.0.21 dev tun0
10.150.0.21 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.150.0.22
43.241.61.245 via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.150.0.21 dev tun0
172.16.0.0/12 via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0
172.31.32.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.35.37
172.31.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.35.37 metric 100
192.168.0.0/16 via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: Can you connect via the VPN? The described effect would happen if all traffic is sent via the VPN (even if it did not come from there). So the interesting information is the output of `ip route`.

Comment: No, I can't connect through the VPN ip either. However I may able to get the output of `ip route` by dumpling the output to a file and read after rebooting the instance.

Comment: In that case, save time and dump more data: `ip rule`, `iptables -nvL`, `ip route show table all`

Comment: Updated the question with output of above commands. I ran `ip route` instead of `ip route show table ` because the `show` command was not there.

Comment: Have you checked the security policy?

Comment: Already opend incoming ports from all IPs. Anything else to change?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the services that listens to the specific ports replies with the original destination port as the replying source port (or even any non-random specific ports), you can have ip rules like:

```
ip rule add iif lo ipproto tcp sport 22 table 123
```

and have the direct route to the LAN (gateway) and the default route in the table:

```
ip route add 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 table 123 / ip route add 172.31.32.0/20 dev eth0 table 123
ip route add default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth0 table 123
```

Or if you can and want to, you may avoid having the "de facto default route" that leads to the tunnel in the main table (e.g. by removing/ignoring `redirect-gateway ...` in the case of openvpn) and add one manually (e.g. with the `up` script directive) to a new table, then have the aforementioned ip rules look up the main table, but with another rule of lower priority than it (but higher than 32766) look up to the new one. This way you don't need to change your configurations when the LAN subnet changes because of DHCP (and gateway doesn't matter / isn't necessary for tun routes).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you how to configure expressvpn so that the problem disappears but the problem is

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.150.0.21 dev tun0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.150.0.21 dev tun0
```

That is a de facto default route via the VPN.

The question is: What shall be delivered via the VPN? Which source addresses are possible via the VPN at all?

If e.g. the VPN is used for 10.150.0.0/24 only then you need such an entry in the routing table.

The "worst" case would be that all source addresses are possible and that you want to respond the way the request came in. This is an obvious intention but unfortunately there is no single switch for turning that on. You would need advanced routing for that i.e. you would have to create (by your own scripts or new versions of SystemD) separate routing tables for both interfaces and install policy routing (`ip rule`) for selecting the appropriate routing table; in this case based on the IP address under which the system was contacted (VPN address or public address).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I want to have is to allow traffic coming from port `22`, `9091` and `443` to go through `eth0` and everything else to go through `tun0`. I can do my own research for this if it's too hard to give specific instructions. Can you explain what is needed to be done in high level. thanks

Comment: @Sudheera I really suggest using the target address. You can use the packet filter for thowing all connections to eth0 away which do not go to posts 22, 9091, or 443. Routing is layer 3 (IP), ports are layer 4 (TCP). If you really want to use the ports then you have to mark the packets (fwmark) with Netfilter and use fwmark in policy rules. That is no fun. And you would not be able to connect to those ports via the VPN. Have a look at https://lartc.org/howto/

Comment: `And you would not be able to connect to those ports via the VPN.` This can be avoided in many ways, e.g. have `from $LAN IP` in the ip rule, or even just add necessary route(s) to the new table. (In the case of "commercial VPN" you hardly want connection from the tunnel to your services anyway.)

Comment: @Sudheera I cannot edit my last comment any more. As the answer by Tom Yan shows, port matching has been added to `ip rule`. This is much easier than using packet marks. Nonetheless I stick with my recommendation to use the local address as filter (`from` in `ip rule`).